# Spring data Neo4j, Relationship entity mapping probleme

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am currently working with neo4j for the first time and everything went well except rich relationship. My relationship is mapped to a RelationshipModel object instead of on of my RelationshipEntity class and I can't get why.

Here is my class:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "SEGMENT")
public class SegmentGraphRelationship {

    @GraphId
    private Long graphId;
    @StartNode
    private AbstractGraphNode departureNode;
    @EndNode
    private AbstractGraphNode arrivalNode;
    @Index
    private Long itineraryId;
    @Index
    private Long segmentId;
    @Index
    private Long transportPlanId;

    private String type;

    @Convert(DateConverter.class)
    private OffsetDateTime departureDate;

    @Convert(DateConverter.class)
    private OffsetDateTime arrivalDate;

    //Emtpy constructor and get/set
}
```

And here is the object I get:[mapped object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuCRK.png)

The properties that are not nodes or type are affected to a properties ArrayList instead of my class properties. I tried to remove the dates properties because there is not date in the graph database but nothing changes. I also tried to add @Property annotation.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When did you intercept the loading? Neo4j OGM that works behind the scenes of Spring Data Neo4j uses the `RelationshipModel` as an intermediate object to collect all information before creating your domain object.